# System.AccessViolationException - crashing app pool

Tags: asp.net, iis

We've got an application which has been running fine, but recently it's app pool has been randomly crashing. No useful information is in the Event Log.

I used the Debug Diagnostic Tool to try and capture the actual exception, and that revealed the following:

In w3wp__leasing***.b***.uk__PID__4232__Date__09_28_2018__Time_11_20_36AM__947__Second_Chance_Exception_E0434352.dmp an unhandled .net exception happened on 41 and has caused the process to crash.

When an unhandled exception is thrown in a Microsoft ASP.NET-based application that is built on the Microsoft .NET Framework 2.0, the application unexpectedly quits because the default policy for unhandled exceptions has changed in the .NET Framework 2.0. By default, the policy for unhandled exceptions is to end the worker process.

Exception Details
System.AccessViolationException
Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

at System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus) 
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags) 
 at System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)

Never seen that error before, and i'm not sure how to troubleshoot it. Could it be a hardware issue?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Such exceptions indicate native memory issues, which won't be easy to troubleshoot without certain skills. Please open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com and share the dump(s) with them.